# Web Analytics Report for Top Pages lists the /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx

Tags: web-analytics, reports

Web Analytics Report for Top Pages lists the /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx as 1 of the top Pages.

Is there any way we can exclude this page from the reports.
Also is it possible to not consider this page when getting the Top Visitors Report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. I did look into the Sharepoint Reporting Database and found the function fn_WA_GetTopPages

Adding a condition to this function did filter out the /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx page.

But still we did not go with this solution as I dont think it is wise to modify the Sharepoint Database Functions..